# Calling a python script in google vm when an image is uploaded

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm new to google cloud and currently I'm working on my graduation project, where you upload an image from Android app into google cloud storage and when the image is uploaded completely the cloud VM calls a python script to process the image, once the processing is completed it returns the result to the android app.

**My Main problem is**:

1.I don't know how to trigger whenever an image is uploaded completely from the android app into the cloud storage so that I call the python script on cloud VM.
2.how to return the result from the cloud VM into the android app.

**I've done the following**:

1.the android app is ready and it uploads images into the cloud storage.
2.the python script is ready ***(it reads the image from local disk and produces the output result )***

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) how to get a notification when upload to the bucket is done.
The event you are looking for is **OBJECT_FINALIZE**

When the event occurs you will be able to call the python script that will do the post processing.